# Jquery, codeigniter 2.1 issue with file upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have jquery code like this:

```
$(parent).on('click', '.izmeni', function() {

        var clone = $(this).parent().clone();

        var name = $(this).siblings('.name').text();
        var surname = $(this).siblings('.surname').text();
        var info = $(this).siblings('.info').text();
        var email = $(this).siblings('.email').text();   
        var phone = $(this).siblings('.phone').text();   
        var date_birth = $(this).siblings('.date_birth').text();   
        var id_lok = $(this).siblings('.lokacija').val();    
        var id = $(this).siblings('.id').val();             

        <?php $attributes = array('class' => 'update_form'); ?>

        $(this).hide();
        $(this).siblings('.permission').hide();
        $(this).siblings('strong').hide();
        $(this).parent().wrapInner('<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload', $attributes);?></form>');
        $(this).parent().prepend('<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />');
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="lokacija"></div>');
        $(this).parent().append('<select name="pol"><option value="m">Muški</option><option value="f">Ženski</option></select>');        
        $(this).parent().append('<input type="submit" value="Submit" />');
        $(this).parent().append('<a id="otkazi">Otkazi</a>');

        $(this).siblings('.name').replaceWith('<input name="name" value="' + name + '" />');
        $(this).siblings('.surname').replaceWith('<input name="surname" value="' + surname + '" />');
        $(this).siblings('.info').replaceWith('<textarea name="info">' + info + '</textarea>');       
        $(this).siblings('.email').replaceWith('<input name="email" value="' + email + '" />');
        $(this).siblings('.phone').replaceWith('<input name="phone" value="' + phone + '" />');          
        $(this).siblings('.date_birth').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>form/date_birth", {'date' : date_birth});   
        $(this).siblings('.lokacija').load("<?php echo base_url() ?>form/location", {'id' : id_lok});   

        $(this).siblings('#otkazi').click(function(){
            $(this).parents("div:first").replaceWith(clone);
            $(this).show();
        });

        $(".update_form").submit(function(){
            data = $(this).serialize();
            console.log(data);
            forma = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                data : data,
                url : "<?php echo base_url() ?>/user/update_person",
                success : function(){
                    forma.slideUp('slow');
                    $("#all_users").fadeOut('slow', function(){
                        $(this).empty().load("<?php echo base_url() . "ajax/get_all_users" ?>", function(){
                            $(this).hide().slideDown('slow');
                        })
                    });
                }
            })
            return false;
        });
    });
```

and PHP code:

```
function update_person(){

           if($this->person_img_upload() != false){$data['picture'] = $this->person_img_upload();}else{echo "131231";}

               $data = array(
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'surname' => $_POST['surname'],
            'telephone' => $_POST['phone'],
            'info' => $_POST['info'],            
            'location' => $_POST['location'],
            'gender' => $_POST['pol'],
            'date_birth' => $this->date()
               );
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            echo $id;
            $this->db->where('id_person', $id);
            $this->db->update('person', $data);
            $this->update_user($id);
           }


function person_img_upload(){
               $config = array (
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
            'upload_path' => $this->path
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $q = $this->upload->data();
        if ( !$this->upload->do_upload()){
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
            return false;}
        else{
            $this->upload->do_upload(); 
            $q = $this->upload->data();        
            return $q['file_name'];
                }     
           }
```

Jquery is replacing elements on the page, and it creates form where user can update his data. (this is working fine, update without the image part is working). When I try to update image, I get this error:

> You did not select a file to upload

I also have form to create new user, which use

> function person_img_upload()

and it is working fine (form is not created via jquery). What seems to be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The files are not uploaded through ajax request. You need to submit your entire form or if you want it to do it through ajax then you can post your form through iframe.

Comment: That is beyond my level of knowledge at the moment :D. Simple PHP file upload will have to do for now.